# Xcode Build Error: Duplicate 'Dummy.swift' While Creating build for Unity Game

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

I'm currently working on building a Unity game for iOS, and I'm encountering a persistent issue during the local build process using Xcode. The error message that keeps appearing is as follows:

```
Filename "Dummy.swift" used twice: '/Users/user/Documents/game/unityGame/buildOne/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Dummy.swift' and '/Users/user/Documents/game/unityGame/buildOne//Dummy.swift'
```

- I attempted to resolve the issue by resetting changes from Git.
- I also cleaned the project build in Xcode.

Expectation:

Despite my efforts to troubleshoot, the issue persists, and I have not been able to resolve it. My expectation is to understand the root cause of this error and find a solution that allows me to successfully build the Unity game for iOS using Xcode.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem when building Unity games for iOS using Xcode or has any insights on how to address this specific error, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Are there any 'dummy'swift' files in your project? If there are do you know what they are for?

Comment: Yes, there are two 'Dummy.swift' files in my project. However, I'm not sure why they're there; they appear to be generated automatically after Unity builds the project.

Comment: What is the meaning of the first sentences "This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now."? You should probably delete them.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion caused by those unnecessary sentences; I have removed them. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Problem Resolved - Unity Project Build Failure Due to BidMachine's Dummy.swift File

I'm the original poster, and I wanted to share the solution I found to the issue I mentioned in my question. The problem was that my Unity project included the Dummy.swift file, which was also automatically created by BidMachine during the build process. This conflicting Dummy.swift file caused the build to fail.

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

**Remove the Dummy.swift File** : Delete or remove the Dummy.swift file from your Unity project. Ensure that it is no longer present.

**Rebuild Your Project** : After removing the Dummy.swift file, rebuild your Unity project. This should resolve the build failure issue caused by the conflicting file.